# How to Login through AJAX in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

No i have been stuck here ... can you please help me out...

```
$(':submit').click(function (e) {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var postdata =
    {
        'Email': username,
        'Password': password
    };

    $.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:7651/Home/CheckLogin',
        data: postdata,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('Hi');
        }
    });
 });
```

this is not working ...its not calling the action controller somehow...

my controller action is

```
public string CheckLogin(Users checkuser)
{
    if (db.CheckUserLoginDetails(checkuser.Email, checkuser.Password))
    {
        return "Login Successful:" + checkuser.Email;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Login UnSuccessful";
    }
}
```

please help.... also do i need to prevent the defualt behavior of the submit button like `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: What kind of error you are having ? can you give more details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to do:

- Your LoginController would need to validate the login and return the HTML Fragments containing the Login Status. Note that you don't need a fullblown HTML here. Just the fragments containing the result
- As you probably know, you can utilize [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that you put in your view. To append the Login Result into the DIV, you could use [jQuery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) Here is the snippet that you would need (NOTE: not debugged yet, but roughly something like below)

```
// Override form submit
$("form").live("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        // Get the action URL
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: "POST",

        // get all form variables
        data: form.serialize(),

        // upon success, the fragment of HTML from the Controller will be stored in loginResultHtml
        success: function(loginResultHtml){

            // append the html to your login DIV id using jQuery.html function
            $(#your-login-status-div-id).html(loginResultHtml);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thx... does not completely solve my problem but get to know the $.Ajax method... thank you very much....

Comment: The answer is updated per your new question. Also, I personally (and some in SO) don't people appreciate reverting accepted answer especially when there is only one answer and then use the answer as part of the question for others to answer. It's best to leave a comment next time to the answerer and normally he/she will update the answer for you. We are here to help after all

Comment: Hey mono, sorry i was not aware of that and i am new to stackOverflow so i thought if i mark the answer accepted then my question is gonna close and everyone thinks that the i have got my answer... so thats why i reverted the accepted answer....:(

Comment: No worries, I understand that :) Next time, don't accept the answer until you are 100% sure your question is answered and keep asking via comments or chat if you think a particular answer is close to answering your question. People here are normally giving hint that would solve the problem and so if you don't that will solve it, you should ask for clarification or tell them it's not enough. Is your problem solved now?

Comment: yup...thx ... everything is working fine now ... i have posted another query related to jquery if you can help on that will be great..please have a look at this post ..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300996/how-to-disable-button-and-jquery-code-for-that-button-asp-net-mvc-3