# how to disable button and Jquery code for that button - asp.net mvc-3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

there seems to be another problem ..not with JQuery code but with Action controller code...

i am putting the breakspoints on controllers and start debugging the app, its straight away going to controller and trying to pass in the null values ...please have a look and let me know... thx

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        UsersRepository repo = new UsersRepository();
        DBHelpers db = new DBHelpers();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var users = new Users();
           return View(users);
        }

        public ContentResult CheckLogin(Users checkuser)
        {
            checkuser = new Users();
            if (db.CheckUserLoginDetails(checkuser))
            {
                return Content("Login Successful:" + checkuser.Email);
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Login UnSuccessful");
            }
        }


        public ContentResult Register(Users userRegister)
        {
            userRegister = new Users();
            if (db.InsertNewUSerDetails(userRegister))
            {
                return Content("Registration Successful : your ID is : " + userRegister.UserID);
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("There was a problem addding you, please try again");
            }
        }
    }
```

=================

## here is my DBHelpers class

```
UsersRepository db = new UsersRepository();

        public bool CheckUserLoginDetails(Users user)
        {
            return (from u in db.EUsers where u.Email == user.Email & u.Password == user.Password select u).Any();
        }

        public bool InsertNewUSerDetails(Users newUser)
        {
            newUser = new Users();
            try
            {
                var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
                newUser.JoiningDate = date;
                db.EUsers.Add(newUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEX)
            {
                foreach (var validationerrors in dbEX.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var valerror in validationerrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", valerror.PropertyName, valerror.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        }
```

## }

## and here is my Users class

```
public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int UserID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public virtual string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public virtual DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }

    }
```

==============
problem is when i try to run the application, its directly going to Register() action and passing the null values ...

please help...

=================

## here is my View Code...

```
@model Temp1.Models.Users

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js") type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    <fieldset>
    <div id="divLoginInfo">
    <p>if not registered, please @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Home", new { @id = "lnkRegister" })</p>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "text" })
    <br />
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "text" })

    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="btnLogin" />
    </p>

    <div id="Result">
        <div class="Loading" style="display:none;"> Checking....</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br />

    <div id="divRegisterInfo" style="display:none;">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Users</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
       <p>
            <input type="button" value="Create"  id="btnRegister" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <div id="divShowRegistrationMessage">

             </div>
        </p>

    </fieldset>

    </div>
}



<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnLogin').click(function (e) {
        var email = $('#Email').val();
        var Password = $('#Password').val();
        var postdata =
        {
            "Email": email,
            "Password": Password
        };
        $('.Loading').fadeIn(50);
        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("CheckLogin","Home")',
            data: postdata,
            success: function (msg) {
                var data = msg.split(':');
                $('#Result').html(data[0]);
                $('.Loading').fadeOut(50);
             },
            error: function (data) {

                $('#Result').html(data);
                $('.Loading').fadeOut(50);
            }

        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#lnkRegister').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#divLoginInfo').fadeOut(100);
        $('#divRegisterInfo').fadeIn(100);
    });

    $('#btnRegister').click(function (e) {

        var firstName = $('#divRegisterInfo #FirstName').val();
        var lastName = $('#divRegisterInfo #LastName').val();
        var email = $('#divRegisterInfo #Email').val();
        var password = $('#divRegisterInfo #Password').val();
        var postdata =
            {
                "FirstName": firstName,
                "LastName": lastName,
                "Email": email,
                "Password": password
            };

        $("#divShowRegistrationMessage").html('Pleaes wait...');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST'    
            url: '@Html.Action("Register","Home")',
            data: postdata,
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#divShowRegistrationMessage').html(msg);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $('#divShowRegistrationMessage').html(data);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to rephrase your question, and include a lot more code, for anyone to be able to help

Comment: Hi,Please have a look at the updated code ...and let me know ?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a trailing `,` here which might result into a javascript error:

```
var postdata =
        {
            "FirstName": firstName,
            "LastName": lastName,
            "Email": email,
            "Password": password,  // <-- remove this comma
        };
```

The javascript error results into the next line not being executed which is `e.preventDefault();` and thus the form performs a normal submit and not an AJAX submit. IIRC some browsers actually might tolerate this but others not. Anyway, it's invalid javascript and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Hi,i have removed that... still its calling the btnLogin Controller Action ....i dont know whats wrong ...

Comment: @patel.milanb, maybe there's some other javascript error that I am not seeing? If you put an alert after the $.ajax call at the end of the function does it get executed?

Comment: In fact now that I look closer I see this `alert(joiningdate);` in your code and can't see where this `joiningdate` variable is defined. So is it defined somewhere? You may also take a look at the Console tab of FireBug which will show your javascript errors and you won't need to ask such questions.

Comment: Hi, I have done that but now there seems to be another problem ... when i am trying to debug the app and i am also putting the breakpoint on my Action cntroller... its directly calling the controller and which is passing null values and therefor error coming in JQuery ...please have a look at the controllers code for me and let me know... thx

Comment: @patel.milanb, how does the AJAX request that is sent to the server look like in FireBug? What exactly is sent to the server?

Comment: its not even goin to server ... its directly going to Register Action ...here is my Jquery code...

when i am checking through breakpoiints after passing null values through Register Action ..next call is to Jquery code url in btnRegister

Comment: @patel.milanb, are you still talking about the `btnRegister`? You configured it to send an AJAX request to the `Register` action so why does this surprise you? Also in your first line inside the Register action you are destroying your action argument by instantiating a new user: `newUser = new Users();`. May I ask why are you doing this?

Comment: but without even clicking to it how is it possible to send request to the Register Action? i am confused...

in firebug, Console, its showing me 

missing } after property list
[Break On This Error] url: 'There was a problem addding you, please try again',

Comment: @patel.milanb, so you have a javascript error somewhere. Doesn't it show you on which line?

Comment: OK, now that } missing error is gone.. BUT still not able to understand as soon as i start app .. its calling Register...?

Comment: @patel.milanb, maybe that's how you configured your routes and made this action the default one or there is some script that redirects to it.

Comment: routes are default...possible that scripts are redirecting ..but whatever i have in my view i have posted in my question...i am not able to find where the bug is ? ..

Comment: When you look at the Net tab of FireBug you should see the chain of requests being executed. What do you see there? Also what do you see in the Console tab? Is there some AJAX request being executed when you first load the page?

Comment: not at all.. in net tab no request made...directly hitting the BPs...and in console tab

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:7651/Content/Site.css"
Site.css
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:7651/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js%20type="
jquery...s type=
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:7651/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js%20type="
jquery...s type=
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:7651/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js%20type="

Comment: You seem to have messed up something with those script inclusions. The urls look completely wrong. I see it now: you forgot to close your `src` attribute: `src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")"`. You did the same mistake for the other script. And I suppose for the CSS as well. So fix your markup.

Comment: fixed the issue of missing JS files... now what ..net tab - nothing, console tab - nothing...

Comment: @patel.milanb, still the `Register.cshtml` view rendered? What url are you requesting? You seem to have errors everywhere in your code. I really cannot help you anymore. You will have to learn and debug your application yourself. Those are some pretty basic mistakes.

Comment: thats fine mate...now seems to have new error..
s is undefined
ajax()jquery...sdoc.js (line 7320)
url = undefined
options = Object { url="There was a problem addding you, please try again", data={...}, success=function(), more...}
(?)()localhost:7651 (line 148)
e = Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=1315170560487, more...}
handle()jquery...sdoc.js (line 2712)
event = Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=1315170560487, more...}
eventHandle()jquery...sdoc.js (line 2328)
[Break On This Error] callbackContext = s.context || s,

Comment: Feel like heven... everything is working fine ...U were right ..there was a problem with scripts files... i deleted all the files.. and referenced the new one.. all working great...thank you very much ...only one question... still console showing 
syntax error
[Break On This Error] "triggered": }; 
but no worries, just wanted to find out what kind of error is that...

Comment: @patel.milanb, great, I am very happy that you solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're attaching a different click event to each button.

If you're currently doing:

```
$('div').click(function(){});
```

Then insted you'll want to attach a different click event to each button, something like:

```
$('#registerButtonId').click(function(){});
$('#loginButtonId').click(function(){});
```

Comment: hi, thx...please have a look at the updated question and code...and let me know where i am goiing wrong...